# the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in AngularJS

Tags: c#, mysql, angularjs, web-services

**Js:**

```
$scope.GetLocationList = function () {
    var url = "/MasterSvc.asmx/GetAllLocationList";
    var data = {};
    var options = {};
    $http.post(url, data, options).then(function (response) {
        var dbfsr = response.data.d;
        var LocData = {};
        $scope.LocData = dbfsr;
    }).catch(
        function (response) {
            console.log('return code: ' + response.status);
        });
};
```

This is the JS function which is call on `initController()` on page load.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover"
       style="width: 95%;font-size:12px" id="EmpTbl">
    <tr>
        <th>Location Code</th>
        <th>Location Type</th>
        <th>Location Name</th>
        <th>Location Address</th>
        <th>Contact Person</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr dir-paginate="loc in LocData|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">
        <td>{{loc.LocationCode}}</td>
        <td>{{loc.LocationType}}</td>
        <td>{{loc.LocationName}}</td>
        <td>{{loc.LocationAddress}}</td>
        <td>{{loc.ContactPerson}}</td>
        <td>{{loc.ContactNo}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning SelectLocation"
                   data-ng-click="GetLocationDetails(loc.LocationCode)"
                   value="View/Edit" id="SelectLocation" data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target="#myModal" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is HTML code where paginate is use like ng-repeat and also use for pagination.

[image: WebService Screen]
[image: Console Error]

I am trying to bind the table using webService from Mysql database.It working fine when database select records are limit up to 240, But if record are more than 240 it showing me Internal server error 500. How to solve this. Please find the screen and code. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you could get past that threshold, it is not a good thing to do. (There is a config in the web config to dictate the http message size.) It is just simply that you are giving your client too much data in one go. Please do do paging.

Comment: Please use `try-catch` blocks to catch your error and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the max Size in the configuration

add this code in web.config backend

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="52428800" executionTimeout="36000" />
```